# What does java.sql.Blob contain?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

From the doc it says:

> By default drivers implement Blob using an SQL locator(BLOB), which
>   means that a Blob object contains a logical pointer to the SQL BLOB
>   data rather than the data itself.

So if I get a Blob object from the db, I don't get all the bytes of the data but only a stream just like an InputStream to a File in the file system(correct me if I'm wrong).

But now, what if I create the Blob myself from the constructor, for example by using Hibernate's Lobhelper?

There are:

- createBlob(byte[] bytes)
- createBlob(InputStream stream, long length)

What are the properties of the Blob that I get back from both of these constructors? Will the data be right inside the Blob object or will be a stream setup?

Comment: The `Blob` will contain whatever you gave it, and you shouldn't concern yourself with exact details of how that's maintained, since it can change whenever Java is updated. --- If you gave it an `InputStream`, then that's what it has, and it means that you can only ask from the bytes of the `Blob` once, since that exhausts the stream. That one-time-use would be when the data is sent to the database as part of an `INSERT` or `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: The quoted text in your question is about `Blob` objects obtained from the JDBC driver, as a result of a `SELECT` statement, and it describes a common way for drivers to implement a `Blob` sourced from the database. Doesn't mean all drivers do it that way, or that all `Blob` objects are implemented that way.

Answer (score 1):

[`org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.NonContextualLobCreator`](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/engine/jdbc/NonContextualLobCreator.java) class is responsible for Blob creation in hibernate, and it uses [`org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.BlobProxy`](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/engine/jdbc/BlobProxy.java), which actually uses:

- [`BinaryStreamImpl`](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/engine/jdbc/internal/BinaryStreamImpl.java) is used for `createBlob(byte[] bytes)`
  and it is defined as: `BinaryStreamImpl extends ByteArrayInputStream implements BinaryStream`
  `BinaryStreamImpl` uses `ByteArrayInputStream` for holding reference to your array.
- [`StreamBackedBinaryStream`](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/engine/jdbc/BlobProxy.java) is used for `createBlob(InputStream stream, long length)` and it is defined as: `StreamBackedBinaryStream implements Stream`
  `StreamBackedBinaryStream` holds reference to your stream.

So, check the source code links in order to get better understanding what is going on behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

A Blob object in Java is a mapping of Blob (Binary large object object in Sql. Methods in ResultSet, CallableStatement and PreparedStatement can be used on Blob objects. JDBC API allows Blob to be used in the same way as an int with methods like getBlob and setBlob (same as getInt and setInt).

There are certain restrictions on Blob:

1. Equality (or nonequality) operator can't be used
2. OrderBy, Distinct and GroupBy cannot be used.

Storing an integer in Blob would therefore be not recommended.